# Why .htaccess rewrite rule redirecting to unexpected url?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my htacess I have:

```
RewriteRule ^(users)/([a-z]+)$   users.php?action=$2
```

When I type the url : `site.com/users/register/` (yes with the / at the end)

the website redirects me to : `site.com/users.php/register/?action=register`

What is it doing that? when it should not redirect at all.

Also, when I type the url : `site.com/users/register` it sends me to error page!

full code:

```
Header unset ETag
FileETag None

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A86400        
ExpiresByType image/x-icon A2592000
ExpiresByType image/ico A2592000
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A2592000
ExpiresByType text/css A2592000
ExpiresByType image/gif A604800
ExpiresByType image/png A604800
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A604800
ExpiresByType text/plain A604800
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash A604800
ExpiresByType video/x-flv A604800
ExpiresByType application/pdf A604800
ExpiresByType text/html A900
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "\.(flv|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7257600"
</FilesMatch>
# 1 Week
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|pdf|txt)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7257600"
</FilesMatch>
# 10 Minutes
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=3600"
</FilesMatch>


<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>

#Gzip
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
# compress text, HTML, JavaScript, CSS, and XML
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

# remove browser bugs
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent
</ifmodule>
#End Gzip

# NONE
<FilesMatch "\.(pl|php|cgi|spl)$">
    Header unset Cache-Control
    Header unset Expires
    Header unset Last-Modified
    FileETag None
    Header unset Pragma
</FilesMatch>

ErrorDocument 404 http://www.site.ae

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(RSS)/([A-Z][a-zA-z0-9]+).xml$ rss.php?title=$2
RewriteRule ^(articles)/(.*)/$ article.php?s=$2
RewriteRule ^(articles)/(.*)/([0-9]+)$ article.php?s=$2&page=$3
RewriteRule ^(teams)/(.*)/$ teams.php?s=$2
RewriteRule ^(teams)/(.*)/([0-9]+)$ teams.php?s=$2&page=$3
RewriteRule ^(site)/(all)/$ site.php?s=$2
RewriteRule ^(site)/(all)/([0-9]+)$ site.php?s=$2&page=$3
RewriteRule ^(site)/(tag)/(.*)/(.*)/([A-Z]+)/([0-9]+)$ site.php?s=tag&orderby=$4&order=$5&tag=$3&page=$6
RewriteRule ^(site)/(.*)/(.*)/([A-Z]+)/([0-9]+)$ site.php?s=$2&orderby=$3&order=$4&page=$5
RewriteRule ^([A-Z][a-zA-z0-9]+)/?$ show_site.php?title=$1
RewriteRule ^([A-Z][a-zA-z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ show_chapter.php?title=$1&ch_num=$2&page=$3
RewriteRule ^([A-Z][a-zA-z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ show_chapter.php?title=$1&ch_num=$2&page=C
RewriteRule ^(t)/(.*)/$ team.php?t=$2
RewriteRule ^(t)/(.*)/([0-9]+)$ team.php?t=$2&page=$3
RewriteRule ^(contact)/?$ contact.php
RewriteRule ^(add)/(chapter)?$ addchapter.php
RewriteRule ^(add)/(site)?$ addsite.php
RewriteRule ^(add)/(info)?$ addinfo.php
RewriteRule ^(register)/?$ register.php
RewriteRule ^(user)/(.*)/$ usercp.php?page=favorite&user=$2
RewriteRule ^(my-list)/delete/([0-9]+)/$    usercp.php?page=delete&site=$2
RewriteRule ^(my-list)/add/([0-9]+)/$    usercp.php?page=add&site=$2
RewriteRule ^(review)/([A-Z][a-zA-z0-9]+)/$   addreview.php?m=$2
RewriteRule ^(users)/([a-z]+)$ users.php?action=$2
RewriteRule ^(showarticle)/([0-9]+)/$  showarticle.php?id=$2

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?siteat.com 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?site.ae [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ http://i642.photobucket.com/albums/uu145/shnisaka/nohotlinking_zpsf5dd3133.jpg [NC,R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.ae$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.site\.ae\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

**More refined question:**

```
RewriteRule ^(users)/(register)$ users.php?action=register [R=301,L]
```

should redirect from `site.com/users.php?action=register` to `site.com/users/register` right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^users/([a-z]+)/?$ users.php?action=$1
RewriteRule ^users/activate/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-z]+)/?$ users.php?action=activate&Hash=$1&UserName=$2
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} users\.php
RewriteRule ^users\.php - [F]
```

I had to delete my .htaccess and add this to it. It worked with no problems!

Answer (score 0):

Keep your rule like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?siteat\$.com 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?site\.ae$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ http://i642.photobucket.com/albums/uu145/shnisaka/nohotlinking_zpsf5dd3133.jpg [NC,R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.ae$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.ae/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f 
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(RSS)/([A-Z][a-zA-z0-9]+).xml$ rss.php?title=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(articles)/(.*)/$ article.php?s=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(articles)/(.*)/([0-9]+)$ article.php?s=$2&page=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(teams)/(.*)/$ teams.php?s=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(teams)/(.*)/([0-9]+)$ teams.php?s=$2&page=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(site)/(all)/$ site.php?s=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(site)/(all)/([0-9]+)$ site.php?s=$2&page=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(site)/(tag)/(.*)/(.*)/([A-Z]+)/([0-9]+)$ site.php?s=tag&orderby=$4&order=$5&tag=$3&page=$6 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(site)/(.*)/(.*)/([A-Z]+)/([0-9]+)$ site.php?s=$2&orderby=$3&order=$4&page=$5 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([A-Z][a-zA-z0-9]+)/?$ show_site.php?title=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([A-Z][a-zA-z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ show_chapter.php?title=$1&ch_num=$2&page=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([A-Z][a-zA-z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ show_chapter.php?title=$1&ch_num=$2&page=C [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(t)/(.*)/$ team.php?t=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(t)/(.*)/([0-9]+)$ team.php?t=$2&page=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(contact)/?$ contact.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(add)/(chapter)?$ addchapter.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(add)/(site)?$ addsite.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(add)/(info)?$ addinfo.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(register)/?$ register.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(user)/(.*)/?$ usercp.php?page=favorite&user=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(my-list)/delete/([0-9]+)/?$    usercp.php?page=delete&site=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(my-list)/add/([0-9]+)/?$    usercp.php?page=add&site=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(review)/([A-Z][a-zA-z0-9]+)/?$   addreview.php?m=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(users)/([a-z]+)/?$ users.php?action=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(showarticle)/([0-9]+)/?$  showarticle.php?id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Can u explain what u did